# email is not sending in codeigniter..getting errors

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

getting errors while sending mail..Failed to authenticate password. Error: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at 535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials d190sm18198379pgc.53 - gsmtp 
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method..

```
<?php
public function sendmail()
{

        if($this->input->post()){
                $email=$this->input->post('email');
                $config = Array(
                    'protocol' => 'smtp',
                    'mailtype' => 'html',
                    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
                    'smtp_port' => '465',
                    'smtp_user' => 'xxx@gmail.com', 
                    'smtp_pass' => 'xxxxxxx', 
                    'useragent' => 'CodeIgniter',
                    'crlf' => '\r\n',      
                    'newline' => '\r\n'   

                );
                $this->load->library('email', $config); 
                $this->load->library('email');

                $password="<p>This email has been sent as a request to reset our password</p>";
                $from='codescart123@gmail.com';
                $to=$email;
                $subject='forget password';                        
                $this->email->from($from);
                $this->email->to($to);
                $this->email->subject($subject);
                $this->email->message($password);
                if($this->email->send()){
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('email','We sent your password to your Email...!');

                }
                else{            
                    echo $this->email->print_debugger();
                }

        }

    else{
        $this->load->view('adminlogin');
    }

}
```

Comment: Your error message says smart things like *"Username and Password not accepted"* and especially *"Learn more at http://thissuperinformativepage"*. Have you tried reading that error and following the link?

Comment: Btw: good job at sharing your credentials online. This is obviously something you should never ever do! I'd change them ASAP!  - **The actual password I mean**, because the history of your question will remain there, even if you edit it.

Comment: `'crlf' => '\r\n',      //should be "\r\n"`- and that means, you should go learn some basics. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double

Comment: will you please help me to correct this error

Answer (score 1):

Hi I think this will solve your problem.

If you're using gmail for sending like what you put in your question please take some time and try this solution.

- change `'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com'` to `'smtp_host' => 'smtp.gmail.com'`
- add `'smtp_crypto' => 'tls'`
- change `'smtp_port' => '465'` to `'smtp_port' => '587'`
- create an application password in your email account and use it in exchange for your real password in your app credentials.
- enable less secure apps in your email account.

These are the solution that I did when i encountered the problem before. hope it helps.

Comment: that are the changes that you did @Anu

Answer (score 0):

First, As your error says that you need to check the ID, Password properly.

Here is the Complete Code: Try This

```
<?php
public function sendmail()
{

    if($this->input->post()){
        $email=$this->input->post('email');

        $config = Array(
            protocol' => 'smtp',
            'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com', //Your Host
            'smtp_port' => '25', 
            'smtp_user' => 'xxx@gmail.com', // change it to yours, server email
            'smtp_pass' => 'xxx',
            'mailtype' => 'html',
            'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
            'wordwrap' => TRUE   

        );

        $this->load->library('email', $config);

        $password="<p>This email has been sent as a request to reset our password</p>";
        $from='codescart123@gmail.com';
        $to=$email;
        $subject='forget password';                        
        $this->email->from($from);
        $this->email->to($to);
        $this->email->subject($subject);
        $this->email->message($password);
        if($this->email->send()){
            $this->session->set_flashdata('email','We sent your password to your Email...!');

        }
        else{            
            echo $this->email->print_debugger();
        }

    } else {
        $this->load->view('adminlogin');
    }

}
```

Comment: yes @Anu you can find it [here](https://www.formget.com/send-email-via-gmail-smtp-server-in-php/)